# Loop in R for getting the sum of combinations starting from zero

Tags: r, loops

I have the following equation and I have to write it in R. [image]

The main challenge that I am facing with this coding is that for each i and for each k, I need a sum of combinations (binomial terms in the numerator). Here min{(n-k),Mi} can be 0 for some i and k, specially when k=n. Most importantly a loop cannot be started from 0, but I need it!

For your kind consideration, here is my code and the data (d1). You will see that I need to start the loop from 0 after the line `sum<-0`, which is my main problem. Would you please see the issue and correct the code? What should I do with the loop that needs to be started from 0?

```
n<-4

n^2

id<-1:16

r<-c(1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1)

tr<-rep(0,n^2)
for(i in 1:n^2){
tr[i]<-ifelse(r[i]==1,rexp(1,1/1),0)
}

t0<-rep(0,n^2)
for(i in 1:n^2){
t0[i]<-ifelse(r[i]==0,rexp(1,1/1.5),0)
}

#Total number of subjects who cannot get B1:

M<-sum(r==0)    #If there were cenoring then M<-sum(r==0 & tr>cenc)

d<-data.frame(id,r,t0,tr)

d1<-d[tr>0,]
d1

d1<-d1[order(d1$tr),]
d1

d1$rank<-1:length(d1$tr)
d1


###Calculating the probability of getting B1 for each subject with r[i]=1:

d1$prob<-rep(0,length(d1$tr))
for(i in 1:length(d1$tr)){  #loop i begins
Mi<-sum(d1$tr[i]>t0[t0>0])
for(k in 1:n){  #loop k begins
sum<-0
for(m in 0:min(n-k,Mi)){    #loop m begins
sum<-sum+choose(Mi,m)*choose(n^2-i-Mi,n-k-m)
}   #loop m ends.
d1$prob[i]<-d1$prob[i]+choose(i-1,k-1)*sum/choose(n^2,n)
}   #loop k ends.
}   #loop i ends.
d1$prob<-d1$prob*1/n
```

Comment: What do you mean *a loop can't be started from zero?* `for( k in 0 :5 ) print(k)` gives  `[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5`

Comment: Actually I tried to mean it cannot do things like the one in the example:
'op<-rep(0,3)
for(o in 0:2){
op[o]<-choose(3,o)
}
op'

Comment: oops, how do I write it in a code mode?

Comment: `op<-rep(0,3) for(o in 0:2){ op[o]<-choose(3,o) } op`

Comment: You can do like this ` op<-rep(0,3); for(o in 0:2){ op[o+1]<-choose(3,o) 
  } ;
  op

choose(3,1)

Comment: what you mean is that you can't **index vectors from zero** (you actually can, using the `Oarray` package, but you should probably just use `op <- rep(0,3) for (o in 0:2) { op[o+1] <- choose(3,o) }; op`)

Comment: Or you could just use `op<-choose(3,0:2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see what is the problem in your original code? You can't index vectors beginning from zero, but it has nothing to do with the range of iterator in loops. Anyway, this should give you same answer but avoids the innermost loop:

```
d1$prob<-rep(0,length(d1$tr))
for(i in 1:length(d1$tr)){  #loop i begins
  Mi<-sum(d1$tr[i]>t0[t0>0])
  for(k in 1:n){  #loop k begins
    # function choose is vectorized, so you can compute all 
    # binomial terms at once given k
    SUM<-sum(choose(Mi,0:min(n-k,Mi))*choose(n^2-i-Mi,n-k-(0:min(n-k,Mi))))
    d1$prob[i]<-d1$prob[i]+choose(i-1,k-1)*SUM
  }   #loop k ends.
}   #loop i ends.
d1$prob<-(d1$prob/choose(n^2,n))*1/n 
#as choose(n^2,n) does not depend on i nor k, 
#you can make the division after the loops for all elements at once
```