# Inclusion of zeros while generating plot titles with for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, histogram, data-visualization, transition

I am trying to plot the frequency vs. number of transitions between different states (0-3). However, I get empty plots in those where state "zero" is included. Changing the state grades to 1-4 solves the problem of the empty plots but consequently, the plot titles are not correct. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602531/loop-in-r-for-getting-the-sum-of-combinations-starting-from-zero) thread where it is stated that a loop can start with zero. Is there any workaround to avoid these empty plots?

Here is the code:

```
n_IDs <- 150
TIME <- 0:100
set.seed(1)
(markov <- data.frame(ID=rep(1:n_IDs,each=length(TIME)),
                      TIME=rep(TIME,n_IDs),
                      STATE=sample(0:3,n_IDs*length(TIME),replace=TRUE)))

transitions <-  data.frame(ID=head(markov$ID,-1),
TIME=tail(markov$TIME,-1),FROM=head(markov$STATE,-1),TO=tail(markov$STATE,-1))

transition_table <- with(transitions,table(FROM,TO,ID))
min_n_transitions <- min(unlist(transition_table))
max_n_transitions <- max(unlist(transition_table))
max_freq <- 50  

par(mfrow=rep(4,2),mai=c(.3,.3,.3,.1))
for ( from in 0:3 ) {
  for ( to in 0:3 ) {
    foo <- transition_table[from,to,]
    hist(foo,freq=TRUE,
         breaks=seq(min_n_transitions-.5,max_n_transitions+0.5),
         xlim=c(min_n_transitions,max_n_transitions),
         ylim=c(0,max_freq),xlab="",ylab="",
         main=paste("From",from,"to",to),
         las=1,col="lightgray")
    mtext('Number of transitions', side = 1, outer = TRUE, line = 2)
    mtext('Frequency', side = 2, outer = TRUE, line = 1.5)

  }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're suing `from` and `to` as index number and in R index 0 does not exist, to use `from` and `to` as row/column name you should use them as characters, 
it should work if you change the line where you define `foo` to the following

`foo <- transition_table[as.character(from), as.character(to), ]`

Comment: That's really good to know, thanks a lot! It works totally fine.